# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for one code but not for the other

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Hello when writing code like:

```
log_likelihood = np.sum(np.dot(Y.T, log(AL)), axis=0)
```

I have an error like:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-888-ac02c17e518d> in <module>()
----> 1 parameters = L_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims, num_iterations = 7, print_cost = True)

<ipython-input-887-d06b73757846> in L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate, num_iterations, print_cost)
     37         # Compute cost.
     38         ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
---> 39         cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)
     40         ### END CODE HERE ###
     41 

<ipython-input-880-a836c239755d> in compute_cost(AL, Y)
     81 
     82     #log_likelihood = -np.log(AL[range(m),(Y.argmax(axis=1))])
---> 83     log_likelihood = np.sum(np.dot(Y.T, log(AL)), axis=0)
     84         #log_likelihood = -1 * np.sum(1 * np.log(AL[range(m),(Y.argmax(axis=1))]))
     85     #print("Y argmax = " + str(Y.argmax(axis=1)))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

But when writing my code as:

```
log_likelihood = -np.log(AL[range(m),(Y.argmax(axis=1))])
```

Then my program is executing without any errors.
On top of the program I already added

```
import math
import logging as log
```

But this doesn't seem to solve my problem!
Anybody knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hello the problem has been solved.
We have to use:

```
log_likelihood = np.sum(np.dot(Y.T, np.log(AL)), axis=0)
```

In stead of:

```
log_likelihood = np.sum(np.dot(Y.T, log(AL)), axis=0)
```

So using np in front of log. 
Clarification: the name of the log function in numpy is np.log